# Locating a kickstart file on a client

Tags: kickstart

I accidentally deleted my custom Ubuntu 16.04 kickstart file from my PXE server. I remember seeing it as a local file on a client that used this server and kickstart to install Ubuntu, but I can't find it anymore.

Does somebody know where the kickstart is downloaded locally, or if I'm wrong and the kickstart never leaves the server?

I could try to find it with 'find', but I'm not sure of the exact name of the file either...

Answer (score 0):

It may only be a feature in Fedora. I just installed Fedora 24 from a PXE and sure enough I have an 'anaconda-ks.cfg' and an 'original-ks.cfg'. The original one is the one I wrote, the other I assume was generated by anaconda using the original, and the one eventually used during installation.

They're located in the root home (/root) of the client. I guess that's not how it works on Ubuntu.

Also, none of those names is the one I used for my ks stored on the PXE server.